# How do I move records up and down in a gridview?

Tags: asp.net, sorting, gridview

How do I make it so when users click on an 'up' or 'down' button in a gridview that it moves the records visibly up and down in the list of records for that gridview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data source will need to have a sort order in it and you need to update the sort order on your datasource whenever one of those buttons is clicked.  How exactly you do that is going to depend on what your data source is.

Let's say, for simplicity, it's a datatable.  Your datatable will have a column like `SortOrder` that would be an integer value, sorted smallest to largest.

One technique is to write event handlers for the buttons' `OnClick` events.

For the **MoveUp** button, you would decrement the current row's `SortOrder` by 1 and increment the previous row's `SortOrder` by one.

For the **MoveDown** button you would increment the current row's `SortOrder` by 1 and decrement the following row's `SortOrder` by 1.

After that you would rebind the datagrid to your updated data source.